# How to feed wire to a 400 Amp meter base?

Tags: electrical

I'm in WA. PoCo is Mason PUD #1. AHJ is WA L&I. I'm wiring up a https://www.homedepot.com/p/Milbank-400-Amp-4-Terminal-Ring-Type-Link-Bypass-Overhead-Meter-Socket-R3548-X/202504185. I'm feeding 2 @ 600 MCM AL XHHW-2 and 1 @ 250 MCM AL XHHW-2 from overhead. I wish I could find pix of it wired, but all I find are unwired pix. I've included one of those pix.

Clearly the two hot lines come from the top and feed to the (outer) line lugs (after flipping them from the bottom to the top per instructions). My question is this. What is the best way to feed in the neutral line? Option1) Straight down the middle, then to the right side neutral lug. Option 2) Bend to the left, go the left of the line lug then a gentle curve to the right side neutral lug. Option 3) Bend to the right, go down, then make a sharp turn (more like an upside down question mark) to the right side neutral lug?

Also, do I need to feed any ground to the meter base? I have two 2" metal nipples at the bottom that will feed load to two 200A panels on the other side of the wall. Is that metal to metal to metal sufficient?

[image]

Here's a pic of where I am so far...
[image]

Comment: Can you rotate the neutral lug to face up and route the neutral all the way to the right?  Also, I'm suspicious of the tiny screws holding the 400a main lugs, there should be two studs there. There is a stud on the top of each main bar.  Check your box spec, but I think that's a legit mounting for the main lugs (unless that's just where the insulator holds mount!)

Comment: The two screws holding the two line lugs are the same two screws that previously held the lugs in the downward direction. The instructions that came with the box said that to feed the wires from the top, to unscrew the lugs, mount them where I did and tighten each screw to 100-150 in-lbs, so that's what I did. I like your idea of rotating the neutral lug. For now, I fed it next to the left hot, then followed the left load bar, came down between the two load bars, then made a right turn to the neutral lug. Unless that's "wrong", I'd like to leave it alone. See pic above (I hope).

Comment: @TomGetzinger -- I'd have routed the neutral down the left side of the pan and under the load lugs, either that or you can try poking Milbank tomorrow about rotating the neutral lug

Comment: I think you are done, looks good like that,  if all the lugs are to torque (I like your torque stripes!) The conduits through to the house will be 2 200amp subfeeds?  Where will the main disconnects be? And the ground/neutral bonding?

Comment: main disconnects in the panels on the other side of the wall from this. I know that is not 2020 compliant, but AHJ said if I complete before Oct 29, I'm good. Ground/neutral bonding - good question. I'll install the ground bonding screw in each of the two panels, bonding the neutral/ground buses to their panels, run a wire from gnd bar 1 to gnd bar 2 to panel 1 gnd bus to panel 2 gnd bus (hope that makes sense - I could add pic). Q: can I feed gnd wire from panel 1 through opening at bottom of meter box, to other opening, to panel 2, or should I just go thru studs inside?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, any idea how I poke Milbank? I originally asked a Q about this box on Home Depot's website (what size allen socket was needed for the lugs). The answer from Milbank was they didn't know (really?). Would I call the local distributor (in Kent, WA) or call the company directly?

Comment: Your local jurisdiction is not requiring disconnects at the meter?  This is in the 2020 code  I know Oregon has delayed adopting until April because of Covid-19 but I would make sure before running your pipe.

Comment: WA adopts 2020 on Oct 29. But I spoke with an inspector who said as long as I've purchased the permit prior to that, I can follow 2017. I hope a second inspector would say the same thing.

Comment: @TomGetzinger -- you can try calling the company directly